# Выполнение цикла до определённого этапа, затем его повтор

Tags: javascript, html

Допустим есть цикл `for (var i = 50; i > 0; i-=10)` и любая кнопка`<button></button>` , как сделать чтобы `i-=10` выполнялось один раз, а при следующем клике на кнопку повторялось уже c изменённой `i`?

Comment: не "повтор", а "продолжение". Только при чем тут цикл?

Comment: Хорошо, а как мне это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i = 50;
function myFunction() {
  if (i > 0) {
    // use i here
  }
  i-=10;
}

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Легче чем я думал, спасибо большое.